# Misaligned Elements in New Tab

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, alignment, positioning

I'm working on an internal project and I'm running into a very strange issue. This project will be stored locally and ran from a shared drive. No web server or anything like that.

When I double-click the file to open it, everything renders correctly. If I hit refresh, it re-renders great, as well. However, when I open a new tab and paste the file-path into the address bar it **-sometimes-** renders incorrectly. It doesn't happen all the time, but I'm gonna guestimate that it does it wrong about 80% of the time, when pasting the file path into a new tab. Upon refreshing the tab, all is well again.

So my question is: what could possibly be causing this? Why doesn't it happen -all- the time? Since this is for internal uses only, I can simply let users know to hit refresh, so it's not that big of a deal. I'm just extremely curious why this is happening.

See below for screenshots. Left is the correct rendering.

[image: Right] [image: Wrong]

Edit: A bit about the code: due to policies, I cannot simply paste everything here, but the elements are contained within a `ul li` that has `text-align: left`. Each element has `float:right`. Text labels are flushed left in the containing `li`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDE2u/) - static

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NJX2u/) - with JS

Comment: can you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: You don't need to paste EVERYTHING. But you need to provide enough for us to find your bugs and errors.

Comment: Updated to include JSFiddle. I'm still curious, though.. what bug could there possibly be in the HTML/CSS that would only happen -sometimes- when pasting into a new tab?

Comment: Added another JSFiddle with JS functions. Any help in figuring this out is greatly appreciated!